# How to get callback for cocos targeted action

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a game with cocos2d-x-3.15.1 where I have an item which I am moving. I want to get a callback called when the action is done.
For this I have used following code structure.

```
    TargetedAction* const targetedAction = TargetedAction::create(item, action);
    CallFunc* const dispatchEvent = CallFunc::create([this]()
                                                           {
                                                               _eventDispatcher->dispatchCustomEvent(EVENT);
                                                            });
    auto itemsMoveAction = Sequence::createWithTwoActions(targetedAction, dispatchEvent);
    runAction(itemsMoveAction);
```

But my code, sometimes fails to execute correct and I suspect that is becouse of this
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/18046 Sequence fails to complete. #18046 bug.
How can I achieve the same functionality without using `Sequence`?

Edited:
I have applied workaround

```
ActionEase* const action = MoveTo::create(timeToStop, destinationPoint);
item->runAction(action);
CallFunc* const dispatchEvent = CallFunc::create([this]()
                                                       {
                                                           _eventDispatcher->dispatchCustomEvent(EVENT);
                                                        });
auto delayAction = Sequence::createWithTwoActions(DelayTime::create(timeToStop), dispatchEvent);
runAction(delayAction);
```

I wanted to completely avoid using Sequence, but it seems there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

// demo

```
auto move = MoveBy::create(3, Vec2(VisibleRect::right().x-130,0));
auto move_back = move->reverse();    
auto delay = DelayTime::create(0.25f);
auto seq1 = Sequence::create(move, delay, move_back, delay->clone(), nullptr);
auto a2 = _grossini->runAction(RepeatForever::create(seq1));

a2->setTag(1);
```

Comment: I wanted to completely avoid using Sequence.